# Powershell multiple expressions in single hash (C#)

Tags: c#, powershell, dns, hashtable

I am trying to retrieve some DNS record data and want to get back both Host Names and their IPv4 Addresses.  After doing some research I have found that in order to get the IPv4 address I need to do a calculated expression:

```
ps.AddParameter("Property",              
        new Hashtable
        {
            {"Name", "RecordData"},
            {"Expression", ScriptBlock.Create("$_.RecordData.IPv4Address")}
        });
```

I can also get the Host Name by either doing a straight forward:

```
ps.AddParameter("Property", "HostName");
```

or similarly to the calculated expression:

```
ps.AddParameter("Property",
    new Hashtable
    {
        {"Name", "HostName"},
        {"Expression", ScriptBlock.Create("$_.hostname,")},
    });
```

My Problem is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to combine both of these simultaneously.  I would strongly prefer to not do separate Select-Object commands so that I can be assured the Hostname and the IPs refer to the same exact DNS Record.

Also I tried just doing these in succession and receive the error:

```
Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Property' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing them in succession is equivalent of doing

```
... |Select-Object -Property {Name="RecordData";Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address)} -Property {Name="HostName";Expression={$_.HostName}}
```

which is why you see the error you get.

You need to supply *an array of hashtables* as the parameter argument value:

```
ps.AddParameter("Property", new object[] {
    new Hashtable
    {
        {"Name", "RecordData"},
        {"Expression", ScriptBlock.Create("$_.RecordData.IPv4Address")}
    },
    new Hashtable
    {
        {"Name", "HostName"},
        {"Expression", ScriptBlock.Create("$_.HostName")}
    }

});
```